# Ошибка 403 Robots.txt Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Всем привет.
Возникает ошибка `403 Forbidden` вместо отображения файла `robots.txt` на Wordpress.
Файл пробовал добавлять в public_html и через плагин DL Robots.

Файл .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off
```

Помогите решить проблему. 
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если файл `robots.txt` реально существует, то стандартный .htaccess, создающийся при установке wordpress, работает отлично.

Comment: @Visman Существует, даже плагин ругаеться http://prntscr.com/fomvb1

Comment: .htaccess стандартный, проблема не в нем. Либо права доступа на файл robots, либо у вас вообще не apache стоит на сервере, либо хостинг дополнительно ограничивает доступ.